# Simplest way to go about transforming data from kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect, bigdata

I am working on a project that pulls data from multiple db sources using kafka connect. I want to then be able to transform the data into a specified json format and then finally push that final json to an S3 bucket preferably using kafka connect to keep my overhead down.

Here is an example of what the data currently looks like coming into kafka (in avro format):

```
{"tableName":"TABLE1","SchemaName{"string":"dbo"},"tableID":1639117030,"columnName":{"string":"DATASET"},"ordinalPosition":{"int":1},"isNullable":{"int":1},"dataType":{"string":"varchar"},"maxLength":{"int":510},"precision":{"int":0},"scale":{"int":0},"isPrimaryKey":{"int":0},"tableSizeKB":{"long":72}}
{"tableName":"dtproperties","SchemaName":{"string":"dbo"},"tableID":1745441292,"columnName":{"string":"id"},"ordinalPosition":{"int":1},"isNullable":{"int":0},"dataType":{"string":"int"},"maxLength":{"int":4},"precision":{"int":10},"scale":{"int":0},"isPrimaryKey":{"int":1},"tableSizeKB":{"long":24}}
```

This looks like so when converted to JSON:

```
{
      "tablename" : "AS_LOOKUPS",
      "tableID": 5835333,
      "columnName": "SVALUE",
      "ordinalPosition": 6,
      "isNullable": 1,
      "dataType": "varchar",
      "maxLength": 4000,
      "precision": 0,
      "scale": 0,
      "isPrimaryKey": 0,
      "tableSize": 0,
      "sizeUnit": "GB"
},
{
      "tablename" : "AS_LOOKUPS",
      "tableID": 5835333,
      "columnName": "SORT_ORDER",
      "ordinalPosition": 7,
      "isNullable": 1,
      "dataType": "int",
      "maxLength": 4,
      "precision": 10,
      "scale": 0,
      "isPrimaryKey": 0,
      "tableSize": 0,
      "sizeUnit": "GB"
}
```

My goal is to get the data to look like so:

```
{
  "header": "Database Inventory",
  "DBName": "DB",
  "ServerName": "server@server.com",
  "SchemaName": "DBE",
  "DB Owner": "Name",
  "DB Guardian" : "Name/Group",
  "ASV" : "ASVC1AUTODWH",
  "ENVCI": "ENVC1AUTODWHORE",
  "Service Owner" : "Name/Group",
  "Business Owner" : "Name/Group",
  "Support Owner" : "Name/Group",
  "Date of Data" : "2017-06-28 12:12:55.000",
  "TABLE_METADATA": {
  "TABLE_SIZE" : "500",
  "UNIT_SIZE" : "GB",
  "TABLE_ID": 117575457,
  "TABLE_NAME": "spt_fallback_db",
  "COLUMN_METADATA": [
  {
    "COLUMN_NM": "xserver_name",
    "DATE_TYPE": "varchar",
    "MAX_LENGTH": 30,
    "PRECISION": 0,
    "SCALE": 0,
    "IS_NULLABLE": 0,
    "PRIMARY_KEY": 0,
    "ORDINAL_POSITION": 1
  },
  {
    "COLUMN_NM": "xdttm_ins",
    "DATE_TYPE": "datetime",
    "MAX_LENGTH": 8,
    "PRECISION": 23,
    "SCALE": 3,
    "IS_NULLABLE": 0,
    "PRIMARY_KEY": 0,
    "ORDINAL_POSITION": 2
  }, ........
```

The header data will mostly be generic, but some of the stuff like date and etc. will need to be populated.

Initially my original thought were that I could do everything utilizing kafka connect, and that I could just create a schema for the way I want the data to be formatted. I am having a problem though with utilizing a different schema with the connectors and I'm not really sure if it is even possible.

Another solution I thought about was utilizing Kafka Streams, and writing code to transform the data into what is needed. I'm not to sure how easy it is do that w/ Kafka Streaming.

And finally a third solution I have seen is to utilize Apache Spark, and manipulating the data with dataframes. But this will add more overhead.

I'm honestly not to sure what route to go, or if any of these solutions are what I'm looking for. So I am open to all advice on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Kafka Connect](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect) does have [Simple Message Transforms (SMTs)](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms), a framework for making minor adjustments to the records produced by a source connector before they are written into Kafka, or to the records read from Kafka before they are send to sink connectors. Most SMTs are quite simple functions, but you can chain them together to slightly more complex operations. You can always implement your own Transformation with custom logic, but no matter what each transform operates on a single record at a time and never should make calls out to other services. SMTs are only for basic manipulation of individual records.

However, the changes you want to make are probably a bit more complex than what is suitable through SMTs. [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/) seems like it is the best solution to this problem, since it allows you to create a simple stream processor that consumes the topic(s) produced by the source connector, alters (and possibly combines) the messages accordingly, and writes them out to other topic(s). Since you're already using Avro, you can write your Streams application to use Avro generic records (see [this example](https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/kafka-streams/blob/master/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/GenericAvroIntegrationTest.java)) or with classes auto-generated from the Avro schemas (see [this example](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/3.2.x/kafka-streams/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/WikipediaFeedAvroLambdaExample.java)).

You also mention that you have data from multiple sources, and chances are those are going to separate topics. If you want to integrate, join, combine, or simply merge those topics into other topics, then Kafka Streams is a great way to do this.

[Kafka Streams apps](http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/index.html) are also just normal Java applications, so you can deploy them using the platform of your choosing, whether that's Docker, Kubernetes, Mesos, AWS, or something else. And they don't require a running distributed platform like Apache Spark requires.

Comment: the link `with classes auto-generated from the Avro schemas (see this example).` is out dated